# CSS white-space: nowrap; broke p tag

Tags: css, tags, nowrap

So I had a P tag grouping some text together so it would not leave the box and so it would look nice but when I added white-space: nowrap; (To make a horizontal overflow) it broke all that and now it is just going out of it's box and cant find a way to fix this.

**Update Code Added**

```
#content {
    width:90%;
    height:450px;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    margin:auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}


#picturePost {
    background:url(images/picture_post.png) no-repeat;
    width:252px;
    height:430px;
    padding-top:25px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-bottom:25px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Then I am just putting the picturePost div inside the content div a couple of times.

Answer (score 1):

The white-space no wrap property means exactly that, that the text will not wrap. Therefore, if your string is longer than the container p tag, it will extend outside of it. This is the appropriate behavior unless I am understanding your question wrong. Perhaps we code look at some code?

**EDIT AFTER ADDING CODE**

Is this what you are looking for then? http://jsfiddle.net/NUZyp/2/

Comment: You can't have multiple id's the same, they should be  <div class="picturePost">.